# How to handle jars in a makefile for a java project

Tags: java, makefile

I need help incorporating jars(specifically mysql-connector-java.jar & javax.persistence_2.1.0.v201304241213.jar) into my makefile. I am aware that Make is not ideal for a java project, but due to requirements, using ant/Maven is not an option. So far my makefile looks like:

```
# Makefile brutally copypasta'd from previous CSC pracs. 

LIB = ../lib
SRCDIR = src
BINDIR = bin
TESTDIR = test
DOCDIR = doc

JAVAC = javac
JFLAGS = -g -d $(BINDIR) -cp $(BINDIR)


vpath %.java $(SRCDIR)
vpath %.class $(BINDIR)

# define general build rule for java sources
.SUFFIXES:  .java  .class

.java.class:
$(JAVAC)  $(JFLAGS)  $<


all: client server

client: shared/NetMessage.class client/Command.class client/UploadConnectionThread.class client/DownloadConnectionThread.class client/MainConnectionThread.class client/ClientState.class client/Main.class
server: shared/NetMessage.class server/ConnectionInstance.class server/ServerState.class server/Main.class

# handling the cyclic dependency between ClientState and the connection thread classes:
client/ClientState.class: client/UploadConnectionThread.class client/DownloadConnectionThread.class client/MainConnectionThread.class

client/UploadConnectionThread.class client/DownloadConnectionThread.class client/MainConnectionThread.class: client/ClientState.java client/UploadConnectionThread.java client/DownloadConnectionThread.java client/MainConnectionThread.java
rm -f $(BINDIR)/client/ClientState.class $(BINDIR)/client/DownloadConnectionThread.class $(BINDIR)/client/UploadConnectionThread.class $(BINDIR)/client/MainConnectionThread.class
$(JAVAC) $(JFLAGS) $(SRCDIR)/client/ClientState.java $(SRCDIR)/client/UploadConnectionThread.java $(SRCDIR)/client/DownloadConnectionThread.java $(SRCDIR)/client/MainConnectionThread.java


# handling cyclic dependency between ServerState and ConnectionInstance
server/ServerState.class: server/ConnectionInstance.class

server/ConnectionInstance.class: server/ConnectionInstance.java server/ServerState.java
rm -f $(BINDIR)/server/ServerState.class $(BINDIR)/server/ConnectionInstance.class
$(JAVAC) $(JFLAGS) $(SRCDIR)/server/ServerState.java $(SRCDIR)/server/ConnectionInstance.java


# All the actual program classes



# compile/run commands
run_server: server
java -cp bin server.Main

run_client: client
java -cp bin client.Main 127.0.0.1


clean:
@rm -f  $(BINDIR)/*.class
@rm -f $(BINDIR)/*/*.class
```

I have researched the Javadocs and other questions on SO, but the answers provided, are for simple project structures where the makefile produces classfiles in the same directory as the java files and no packages are used. In this case however the class files are created in bin/server (if they are server files) or the approriate bin/subdirectory. My project structure is as follows:

```
/bin
  /server/
  /client/
  /shared/
/src
  /server/
  /client/
  /shared/
/lib
   /mysql-connector-java.jar
   /javax.persistence_2.1.0.v201304241213.jar
/makefile
```

I have already tried adding the jars to the classpath as follows: `CLASSPATH = /lib/mysql-connector-java.jar`, but it does not work when I add the class path to the rule: `.SUFFIXES:  .java  .class`, as Make picks it up as multiple targets.

Comment: Instead of `-cp $(BINDIR)`, use `-cp $(BINDIR):lib/mysql-connector-java.jar:lib/javax.persistence_2.1.0.v201304241213.jar`.

Comment: @JBNizet It compiles, which is better than before! But during run time I still get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`, which shows its still not picking up the classes in the package. Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Well, your java commands just pass `-cp bin` instead of passing the correct classpath, including bin and the two jar files.

Comment: @JBNizet Aaaah I did update the java instruction as follows: `java -cp bin server.Main lib/mysql-connector-java.jar:lib/javax.persistence‌​_2.1.0.v201304241213‌​.jar:lib/rs2xml.jar` but still end up with the ClassNotFoundException. (Sorry for not mentioning the updated command).

Comment: The libraries, just as when compiling, must be in the classpath: `java -cp bin:lib/mysql-connector-java.jar:lib/javax.persistence‌​_2.1.0.v‌​201304241213‌​.jar:l‌​ib/rs2xml.jar server.Main`.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks a lot! Finally running.